# Can users accept their own answers equitably?

Tags: discussion, self-answer

Scenario: A user asks a question and receives no response to it. He doesn't want to let the question continue on with no response forever, as he considers it useful. He later finds a solution and answers his own question.

So my question is: if that user answered his own question, how can he accept it? As we all know, everybody will give extra importance to his own answers. In the example case, the user will select the self-answer as correct because it is important to him.

How can the example user objectively decide that his own answer is correct? Why not leave it to a third person or group, like our community?

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17516/what-if-my-answer-is-better-and-the-community-agrees/17518#17518 and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56512/unaccepted-questions-should-go-to-jury

Comment: @Popular The line in you mension "He decides not to letup on working on itself." it's not well. it is not my intension. I want to say that  "I don't want to let my question down due to no responce as it is useful question." that's all.

Comment: @Popular, Now it is correct. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This discussion has already been had. [This blog post](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/11/why-cant-i-accept-my-own-answer/) has Jeff against self answering. In the comments, however, Jeff is convinced to [allow self-answers](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/accept-your-own-answers/).

Read it :)

Comment: oh! yes what i said is already declared. that means if no another answer that my question than it should be accept/decline by community isn't it.?

Comment: @mahesh Not sure if I understand you there -- but here, have an [example of a question where a self answer was a good idea](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/6910/in-100-rogues-is-it-possible-to-sell-items) despite there being other answers.